# How to declare alternative dependencies in a systemd *.service config file?

Tags: systemd

I want do declare a service `myservice` that needs either `mysql` or `mariadb` running as a prerequisite before starting. How can I express that in the `/etc/systemd/system/myservice.service` service definition config file ?